# VS Code does not reach docker engine running in wsl2

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

Docker engine (not docker-desktop) is installed in wsl2 and listening to port 2375. I reach it outside, i.e. from Windows by `http://ip-of-wsl2:2375/_ping` which returns `OK`.

However in VS Code using Docker Extension i can not reach the docker engine. I am using VPN.
Settings of VS Code

```
...
   "docker.host": "tcp://ip-of-wsl2:2375"
...
```

I also have tried with proxy but it did not help

```
...
   "http.proxy": "http://proxy-host:port",
...
```

Comment: You have the port number twice. Typo?

Comment: Typo was only in question and i have adjusted it.